# AS .8.9 Gradle 2.1 Error :~/.gradle/wrapper/dists/... (No such file or directory)

Tags: android, gradle, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin

I'm receiving the error below after installing Gradle. The /wrapper directory does not exist. Gradle -v from terminal within AS .8.9 appears properly installed. My path includes ~/.gradle.
The gradle command without options causes the dowload of many files to subdirectories.

I'd prefer to run gradle only as a local distribution.  I've been trying to resolve this for the past few days, but I'm stuck. Any help is appreciated.

Error:~/.gradle/wrapper/dists/gradle-2.1-all/27drb4udbjf4k88eh2ffdc0n55/gradle-2.1-all.zip.lck (No such file or directory)

### Gradle 2.1

Build time:   2014-09-08 10:40:39 UTC 
Build number: none
Revision:     e6cf70745ac11fa943e19294d19a2c527a669a53

Groovy:       2.3.6
Ant:          Apache Ant(TM) version 1.9.3 compiled on December 23 2013
JVM:          1.7.0_71 (Oracle Corporation 24.71-b01)
OS:           Mac OS X 10.10 x86_64

Comment: Try invalidating caches in AS and restart... AS and gradle commonly have caching issues

Comment: Invalidating the cache has no effect. Thanks for the suggestion, though.